# I am training a keras neural net. I would like to have a custom loss function given by y_true*y_pred. Is this allowed?

Tags: neural-network, keras, loss-function

This is a snippet of my model:

```
W1 = create_base_network(latent_dim)

input_a = Input(shape=(1,latent_dim))
input_b = Input(shape=(1,latent_dim))

x_a = encoder(input_a)
x_b = encoder(input_b)

processed_a = W1(x_a)
processed_b = W1(x_b)

del1 = Lambda(Delta1, output_shape=Delta1_output_shape)([processed_a, processed_b])
model = Model(input=[input_a, input_b], output=del1)

# train
rms = RMSprop()
model.compile(loss='kappa_delta_loss', optimizer=rms)
```

Basically, the neural net is getting a (pre-trained) encoder representation of the two inputs and computing the difference in prediction values for the two inputs by passing through a MLP. This difference is Delta1 which is y_pred of the network. I want the loss function to be y_pred*y_true. However, when I do that, I get the error, 'Invalid objective: kappa_delta_loss'.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

> You almost answer the question yourself. Create your objective
>    function like ones in
>    https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/objectives.py like
>    this,
>
> ```
>  import theano import theano.tensor as T
>
>  epsilon = 1.0e-9 
>  def custom_objective(y_true, y_pred):
>      '''Just another crossentropy'''
>      y_pred = T.clip(y_pred, epsilon, 1.0 - epsilon)
>      y_pred /= y_pred.sum(axis=-1, keepdims=True)
>      cce = T.nnet.categorical_crossentropy(y_pred, y_true)
>      return cce and pass it to compile argument
>
>  model.compile(loss=custom_objective, optimizer='adadelta')
> ```

from https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/369

So you should create your custom loss function with two arguments, the first being the target and the second your prediction.

Assuming your output (y_pred) is a scalar, your custom objective could be

```
def custom objective(y_true,y_pred)
    return K.dot(y_true,y_pred)
```

K for keras backend (more generic than the theano example)